# Feature Selection Before or After kNN Imputation?

Tags: feature-selection, data-imputation, k-nearest-neighbour

From my understanding, kNN imputation is dependent on the variables where any two cases do not have missing values. Thus, would it be ideal to do feature selection before or after imputation?